# I am totally lost in blender and cant find my models

Tags: modeling

I decided it would be fun to press  <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>F</kbd> and go exploring, and now I've lost my pine tree.

I cant just press <kbd>0</kbd> to go to my camera, because I accidentally clicked when in walk mode.

Comment: Locate them in the outliner, then right click on their names in the outliner and press "select". After that, hover in the 3D viewport and press NumpadPeriod to *view selected*.

Comment: Or press Shift C in the viewport to *View All*.

Comment: Home key also works. Many options...

Answer (score 2):

You can always press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to reset your view ;)